# Mutiple checkbox values is not stored to database in php, empty renty showing using foreach

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

While trying to store multiple checkbox values into a database using foreach loop, nothing is entered to the column, I want to enter all the checkbox values, checked values, to single column

Courses:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="course" value="php">PHP 
<input type="checkbox" name="course" value="java">Java 
<input type="checkbox" name="course" value="android">ANDROID

<input type="checkbox" name="course" value="net">.NET
<input type="checkbox" name="course" value="mat">MATLAB
```

Here is the insert code and loop:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $course=$_POST['course'];

    $chk="";
    foreach($course as $chk1)  
      {  
          $chk.= $chk1.",";  
      }

$q="INSERT INTO  application(id,fname,lname,age,sex,edu,addr,course) VALUES ('','$fname','$lname','$age','$gender','$edu','$addr','$course')";
```

Comment: try naming the elements `course[]` and processing the resultant array

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  input name must be an array to hold multiple values. Update your code as,

```
Courses   :  <input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="php">PHP
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="java">Java
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="android">ANDROID<br><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="net">.NET
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="mat">MATLAB<br><br>
```

Also, you can replace your `foreach` with `implode` as,

```
$course = $_POST['course'];
$chk = implode(',', $_POST['course'])
```